# Simplify (1/x)^a / x^2 in sympy

Tags: sympy, simplification

A long operation with sympy yielded the expression `(1/x)^a / x^2`, which one would normally write as `x^(-2-a)`. What is the right sequence of sympy operations that I can apply to arrive to the simplified form?

I have tried the following, and none of them seems to simplify the expression at all.

```py
import sympy as sym

expr = sym.sympify("(1/x)^a / x^2")

print(sym.simplify(expr))
print(sym.expand_power_exp(expr))
print(sym.expand_power_base(expr, force=True))
print(sym.powsimp(expr, force=True))
print(sym.collect(expr, "x"))
print(sym.ratsimp(expr))

# prints (1/x)**a/x**2 every time
```

Comment: They might be able to help you better at [math.se]. No guarantee though

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That simplification can only occurs when [`x` is positive](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=is+%281+%2F+x%29%5Ea+equals+to+x%5E%28-a%29).

```py
from sympy import *
x = symbols("x", positive=True)
expr = sympify("(1/x)^a / x^2", locals={"x": x})
powsimp(expr)
```

Comment: Accepted. Do you know how to do it if `x` was a whole expression, say `y+z`? I mean, simplifying `(1/(y+z))^a / (y+z)^2`

Comment: Sadly, sympy's assumption system is not that advanced. In this case I would replace `y+z` with a positive symbol, perform the simplification, then substitute the symbol with `y+z`.

Comment: If y and z and a are all declared positive then it will work. Otherwise `powsimp((1/(y+z))**x / (y+z)**x, force=True)` can be used.

Comment: This method also works: `sym.powdenest(expr, force=True)`